# How to call and get response with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making my own website for my Internet Software Development class. I'm new to web coding. I'm familiar with Java and some other languages, but except for HTML, I'm new to website design. I started using PHP and Javascript two weeks ago, but I've picked up a lot so far. Anyway, I've hit a roadblock in my design.

Let me explain my site first. I'm doing a trivia website. Users will log in, and a SQL query will give the user a question they haven't answered yet, along with 4 possible answers on the left side of the screen. When the user clicks the "submit" answer button, I want 2 things to happen: 1) A new question to show up on the left side of the screen, and 2) The result of the previous question (either "Correct" or "Incorrect. Correct answer was...") to show up on the right side of the screen.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this. I can get a new question to show up, but I can't get the result to display. I've spent at least 12 hours on this web page so far, and I'm completely stuck. I've spent quite a bit of time on google, and I think I need to use Ajax, but I'm not familiar with Ajax, and all my attempts to utilize it have failed miserably. I would appreciate any help you could give me.

Here is my trivia page code:

```
    <?php
ob_start();
include_once 'functions.php';
include 'header.php';


//Trivia category
$category = 1;

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

getNewQuestion($user, $category);



$postValue = $_POST['value'];



echo <<<_END

 <html lang="en">
 <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Trivia</title>

        <!-- Add bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Import jumbotron -->
        <link rel="bootstrap-3.0.0/examples/jumbotron/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Import custom CSS -->
        <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

_END;
?>
        <script>
        function reportError()
        {
        alert("Report question error option not yet available.");
        }
        </script>

        <script>
        function returnAnswer()
        {

            if ($postValue == $optionValue)
            {
            queryMysql("INSERT INTO membersAnswers (user, category_id, question_id, score)
                VALUES ('$user', '$category', '$newQuestion[question_id]', '1')");

            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=='Correct!';
            $msg = 'Correct!';
            alert($msg);
            }

            else
            {
            queryMysql("INSERT INTO membersAnswers (category_id, question_id, score)
                VALUES ('$category', '$newQuestion[question_id]', '0')");
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=='Incorrect. Correct Answer: $correctAnswer.';
            $msg = 'Incorrect. Correct Answer: $correctAnswer.';
            alert($msg);
            }
            }


        </script>
<?php
echo <<<_END
 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="container"  STYLE="background-color:white;">
    <!-- Serves as wrapper for page content. -->

        <!-- Create title header at top of page -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Play</h1>  <!-- Header -->
        <h2>Test your knowledge against your friends and earn achievements!</h2>
        <p>This site is still in development.</p>
        </div>
  </div><!-- .container -->


<div class="container" STYLE="background-color:white;">
<div class="row">

<!------extra space on left--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="col-md-1"></div>

<!------question box ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="col-md-5" style="border: 2px solid black">
    <form class="form" id="form" method="post">

        <h3 class="questions" id="id">$question</h3>
        <br/>

    <div class="radio"   style="font-size: 20px;">

        <input type="radio" value="option1" name="option" id="1">$answer1<br/>

        <input type="radio" value="option2" name="option" id="2">$answer2<br/>

        <input type="radio" value="option3" name="option" id="3">$answer3<br/>

        <input type="radio" value="option4" name="option" id="4">$answer4<br/>

        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id="optionsRadios">
        <br/>


    </div>


<br/>
<button type="button" name="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="returnAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
<br/><p>  </p>

<button type="button" name="errorBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="reportError()">Report an error</button>
<br/><p>  </p>

<button type="submit" name="nextBtn" class="btn btn-primary" action="trivia.php">Next Question</button>
<br/><p>  </p>
</form>

</div> <!--End div class col-md-5 -->

<!------extra space in middle------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>

<!------answer box----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid black">
<h3>Previous Question:</h3>
<p id="result">$msg</p>
<p>  </p>
<button type="button" name="errorBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="reportError()">Report an error</button>
<br/><p>  </p>
</div> <!--End div class col-md-3 -->

<!------extra space on right--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="col-md-1"></div>

_END;
?>


</div> <!--End div class row -->
<p></p> <!-- Add extra space below question border -->
</div> <!--End div class container -->



<!-- Import to use navbar -->
<script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Import to use dropdown list
<script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/js/dropdown.js"></script> -->

<!-- Import so that menu becomes mobile menu on smaller screens -->
<script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of my functions.php code that includes the "getQuestion" function called in the above script:

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 
$dbuser = 
$dbpass = 
$dbname = 

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());




function getNewQuestion ($user, $category)
{
    global $question;
    global $answer1;
    global $answer2;
    global $answer3;
    global $answer4;
    global $optionValue;
    global $question_id;

    $query = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM questions
                        LEFT JOIN membersAnswers
                        ON membersAnswers.user = '$user' AND questions.question_id = membersAnswers.question_id
                        WHERE membersAnswers.question_id IS NULL AND questions.category_id = '$category'
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 1;");

if (mysql_num_rows($selectQuestion))
    {

    $newQuestion = mysql_fetch_array ( $query );
    $question = $newQuestion['question_name'];
    $answer1 = $newQuestion['answer1'];
    $answer2 = $newQuestion['answer2'];
    $answer3 = $newQuestion['answer3'];
    $answer4 = $newQuestion['answer4'];
    $question_id = $newQuestion['question_id'];

    if ($newQuestion['answer'] = '1')
    {
    $correctAnswer = $newQuestion['answer1'];
    $optionValue = "option1";
    }
    elseif ($newQuestion['answer'] = '2')
    {
    $correctAnswer = $newQuestion['answer2'];
    $optionValue = "option2";
    }
    elseif ($newQuestion['answer'] = '3')
    {
    $correctAnswer = $newQuestion['answer3'];
    $optionValue = "option3";
    }
    elseif ($newQuestion['answer'] = '4')
    {
    $correctAnswer = $newQuestion['answer4'];
    $optionValue = "option4";
    }

    return $question;
    return $answer1;
    return $answer2;
    return $answer3;
    return $answer4;
    return $optionValue;
    return $question_id;

}

else {
    echo "There are no more questions at the moment.";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm not sure if this info is necessary, but here are the fields for the two relevant tables:

questions (question_id, question_name, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer [the correct answer written as 1,2,3, or 4], category_id)

membersAnswers(user, category_id, question_id, score)

I've searched this site to try to find what I'm looking for, but I couldn't find anything. I really hope someone here can help me. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I added the code that almost worked the best; I thought that might be the most helpful. Unfortunately, that didn't include any of my attempts using Ajax.

Here's what I added in the trivia.php page to try to work Ajax. This was added in the header.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function correctOrNot(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getResult.php",
            data:   "answer1=" + document.getElementById("answer1").value +
                    "&answer2=" + document.getElementById("answer2").value +
                    "&answer3=" + document.getElementById("answer3").value +
                    "&answer4=" + document.getElementById("answer4").value +
                    "&optionValue=" + document.getElementById("optionValue").value +
                    "&postOption=" + $_POST['option'] +
                    "&user=" + $_SESSION['user'] +
                    "&category=" + '1' +
                    "&question_id=" + document.getElementById("question_id").value,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(html){
                $("#result").html(html);
            }
        });
        }
</script>
```

And here is the getResult.php code:

```
    <?php
include_once 'functions.php';

if ($postOption == $optionValue)
{


queryMysql("INSERT INTO membersAnswers (user, category_id, question_id, score)
    VALUES ('$user', '$category', '$question_id', '1')");

echo 'Correct!';
}

else
{
queryMysql("INSERT INTO membersAnswers (user, category_id, question_id, score)
    VALUES ('$user', '$category', '$question_id', '0')");

echo 'Incorrect. Correct Answer: $correctAnswer.';
}
```

?>

Comment: Show one of the failed attempts to use AJAX, so we can help you fix it. We're not going to write the code for you from scratch.

Comment: Sorry. I added the code that almost worked the best; I thought that might be the most helpful. Unfortunately, that didn't include any of my attempts using Ajax, which didn't occur to me as a problem, probably because I'm severely sleep-deprived from spending so much time on this site. I added the AJAX attempts at the end of the post.

Comment: Do you really think that anyone will read your messy, outdated code and fix it for you ?

Comment: @Panique- I didn't ask for someone to fix it. I asked for help. I don't care if that comes in the form of a general tip, a website link, or code. And frankly, I don't care if someone reads all my code or not. I just wanted to provide enough information so that someone could point me in the right direction. As for it being "messy" and "outdated," I did say that I've been doing this for two weeks. I apologize if it's too messy, but you don't have to read it. As for it being outdated, it would be nice if you could do something worthwhile and explain what makes it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need AJAX to do what you're describing, and I'd leave it out as it's just going to add complexity.

First things first, instead of defining global variables in `getNewQuestion()`, you should return [an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and do something like `$questionDetails = getNewQuestion();`, and you could access various properties like `$questionDetails['question']`.  In fact, your use of [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) is flawed, in that after the first `return` call, none of the others will run.  The only reason you're able to access the variables is that you made them global.

Looking at the action on submit, you'll run into issues as you've put PHP into your `<script>` element.  You can't do this as PHP runs on the server, and then, after all your PHP runs, the file is loaded in a web browser.  Any javascript will then be executed in the browser, a.k.a. client-side.

The general way people would do this would be to set the action to another PHP file.  That would submit the data, and then you can parse the form input (usually via [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)).  So, read in all that data, probably do another DB query to get the correct answer based on the question ID, and determine if it was right or wrong, and then render a new question and the previous answer.

Often times, people will do this all in one PHP file, where the beginning of the file contains a check to see if it's a form submission (e.g. something like   `if (!empty($_POST)) { . . . }`).  If it's a submission, you run the check answer stuff.  In all cases, you'd show a new question, and if it's a submission, you could show whether they were right or wrong as well.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! This is exactly what I needed! This explained so clearly what I needed to do. My code works great now! I can't thank you enough!